# MVC 5 - EF 6 - Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am new to MVC development. I have three questions.

1) I created a new project with MVC 5 EF 6.1 from a template. How do I know what version of Identity do I have. Does it come with Identity 2.0 (I download VS 2013 about 6 weeks ago if this helps)

2) I know that once I launch a web page and register one user it create a database. Can I use that same database for the rest of my development? I will have many webforms that will be saved in a database.

3) The database that is created from a user registering is it code-first or database-first?

Comment: I highly recommend you get a book on this. 1) You can check the version in project references. 2) Sure why not but there are options that wipe it on each new app start 3) I believe code first but not 100% on that.

Comment: _packages.config_ will tell you which version of Identity you are using.

Comment: So what would be best practice? Using a db for authentication and one for the rest of my data? I will have online forms and they once they submit the forms I only want them to see their respective forms.

Comment: Not sure if I should start a new thread but here goes. I have MVC 5 EF 6.1.1 and Identity 2.0. I cannot find the IdentityConfig.cs under App_start. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, first I would like to thank everyone who helped me. After downloading the Identity 2.1.0-alpha1 Samples‏ I realized that it was doing all I needed, However, since it is Alpha I cannot use it in production.

I went to the MVC 5 Tutorials from Microsoft and email one of the instructor directly. He just confirmed via email to me that I can now use the samples in production.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would like to mention that MVC(or razor), Owin, Identity and EF are different things and they can be plugged or not. For example you can use Identity without any EF or use FormsAuthintication with Identity. As Mike Cheel mentioned I'll highly recomend to read books on this.

Visual studio 2013 standard MVC5 template is coming with Identity version 1 and Owin 2.0 .
You can look in packages.config to see what version is actually there.
You should us `Nuget` to download newer versions.

As you are searching for IdentityConfig.cs under App_start you may download a newer sample (with Nuget) - **BUT don't do it for production**, because it's using an 2.1.0-alpha1 version of Identity. You can use it for learning.

About Database and EF. Code first, with data migrations is used in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework. You can override it. But it'll be a bad idea for beginner. Also you can use the DB for the rest of your Application.

Comment: Friends, there is only two books out there that I can see. I got the one from apress and he does not mention identity in that book. I think he may have written another book about identity. I am also trying to use identity 2.0 Would you people agree that there is not much help out there? This is all relatively new technology. I have found plenty of good example out there on the web, and I need to find where IdentityConfig.cs file is so I can add email authentication and such. I also need something that I can use in production. By the way, I do appreciate everyone trying to help me.

Comment: I read somewhere that they had the IdentityConfig.cs Identity 1.0, then got rid of it for beta 2.0 and now it is suppose to be back.

Comment: in any case I recommend to use Identity 2.0 and Owin 2.1 they are much better then previous versions.
here is a small introduction
http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/06/22/ASPNET-Identity-20-Customizing-Users-and-Roles.aspx

Comment: Bummer, when I add ( PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre ) I can now see the IdentityConfig.cs but it is in Alpha release, so back to square one. :(

Comment: Can I use email authentication with Identity 1?

Comment: :)
create an empty MVC project. update packages with nuget to Identity 2 and Owin 2.1
then you can copy paste the code from the example: Samples -Pre